# Residues of $df/(f-a)$ for meromorphic $f$.

Tags: differential-forms, residue-calculus, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

Suppose $f$ is a non-constant meromorphic function on a compact Riemann manifold and $a\in \mathbb{C}$. I'm trying to understand why
$$\mathrm{res}_P\left(\frac{df}{f-a}\right) = \frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_\gamma \frac{df}{f-a} = \mathrm{ord}_P(f-a)$$
where $\gamma$ is a simple loop containing $P$ (contained in one coordinate chart).

The proof I'm reading then claims that  since the sum of residues of a meromorphic 1-form is 0, we have
$$ (\mbox{multiplicity of } f=a) = \sum_P \max(0,\mathrm{ord}_P f) $$
and I don't see how this follows.

Comment: Where did $a$ disappear? The first paragraph is just like the usual argument principle.

Comment: It might be a typo in the second line. I'm not too comfortable integrating with respect to $df$; so how would I translate it to an expression involving say $dz$ (assuming $z$ is a local coordinate)

Comment: Yeah, you need to know this :)   $df = f'(z)\,dz$. Now you have it?

Comment: Thanks, any idea what the second line is trying to say?

Comment: I think there's a typo, as I suggested at the beginning. On the right-hand side it should be $\text{ord}_P f-a$. This is pretty much the definition of multiplicity.